# How to link my local MySQL DB to remote MySQL on the internet

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

Please I need some suggestions or advice on how to how to link my local MySQL DB to remote MySQL on the internet.

I developed a Conference Management System for my client and they want us to setup 2 servers; one online on the internet and the other offline on a local server within the premises such that participants who intends to attend can with their mobile device or PC login and register where ever they are using the online server and those who are in the premises but do not know how to use the internet can be attended to by the registration department, who incidentally are connected to the local server.

The essence of both offline and online servers is such that what ever is entered in the each server is synchronized or replicated on the other. The offline version in particular is to handle any downtime that may occur as a result of internet failure in any way. So if the internet speed drops or goes down completely, they will still be working with the local MySQL database and when its back, the 2 servers will update themselves.

Your suggestions and advice is kindly appreciated.

Mike

Comment: You tagged this "MySQL replication", which is the answer to your question.

Comment: @ceejayoz: Yes but the setup process is my issue. I have not done it before and am wondering how I can set it up online. I cant find any materials to study. Can you help please?